# Redefine acronym look in document

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

I would like to redefine the way acronym looks when I use `\acrfull` macro. Now it shows meaning of acronym and then abbreviation in brackets, but I would like it to show the opposite way - abbreviation and then meaning in brackets.

If I put it this way

```
\newacronym{hsv}{HSV}{eng. Hue, Saturation, Value}
```

it shows

> ... eng. Hue, Saturation, Value (HSV) ...

and I would like it to look like

> ... HSV (eng. Hue, Saturation, Value) ...

Is it possible to do something like this only for `\acrfull` macro?

Comment: Hi, please post a MWE with the output of your first quote. That saves us time. Thanks.

Comment: Chapter 13.3 on page 99 in http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf may be of help. You can try to redefine your acronym appearance.

Comment: If you need the same behavior for `\Acrfull` and `\ACRfull` also, let me know and I'll add something in the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine `\acrfullformat` and swap the arguments:

```
\renewcommand{\acrfullformat}[2]{#2\space(#1)}
```

Thus, the following MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\renewcommand{\acrfullformat}[2]{#2\space(#1)}

\newacronym{hsv}{HSV}{eng. Hue, Saturation, Value}

\makeglossaries


\begin{document}

\noindent \acrfull{hsv}.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

gives:

[image]

---

Obviously, the previous solution also affects commands like `\gls`.

If you really want that behaviour only for the command `\acrfull` you can add the following lines to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@acrfull#1#2[#3]{%
  \acrlinkfullformat{\@acrshort}{\@acrlong}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother
```

In this way, the following MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeatletter
\def\@acrfull#1#2[#3]{%
  \acrlinkfullformat{\@acrshort}{\@acrlong}{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}
\makeatother

\newacronym{hsv}{HSV}{eng. Hue, Saturation, Value}

\makeglossaries


\begin{document}

\noindent \gls{hsv} 

\noindent \acrfull{hsv}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

gives the desired result only for `\acrfull`:

[image]